# Different color for highest score answer on profile page

Tags: feature-request

On the users profile page it lists their answers to questions as gray or green if they are the accepted answer. I think if they are not the accepted answer but are the highest scored answer to the question they should come up as a different color, orange maybe. This would indicate that although the asker didn't think it was the best answer, the community did.

Comment: You are left with the question of what to do for highest voted *and* accepted questions.

Comment: @dmckee It would just default to green, in my opinion (or orange depending on what the general consensus of which one has more value).

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, it could display something like "#1 of 5" or "#3 of 10" to indicate the answer's rank for that question.

Comment: Clearly the compromise is to have shades of orange that represent the answer's position in relation to the other answers. Note: I will now be referring to a post's score as its orangeness

Comment: I have the most orangest answer to this question. W00t!

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I like about the design of SO is that the design looks clean; even though, there's a lot of information presented.

I think a new color / rank, would not add much information, and it would sully the design. The absolute number of votes is generally a good indication of the quality / popularity of the answer. There's no need for the added nuance of relative rank.

Comment: A great answer in a popular category will get many more votes than an equally great answer in a less popular category. So I don't think the number of votes alone tell the whole story.

Comment: Also thats why I said orange, because there are already a lot of orange in the theme, so I don't think it would make it any less clean than having some gray and some green.

Comment: @John - It's definitely a judgement call either way. I can understand where you're coming from, but I personally don't think the added information would be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help the general body of users, or would it just serve to give individuals another way to keep score? I don't go to profile pages to see what other questions someone answered well as a matter of course, although I do look at mine to feed my ego from time to time. But I might be atypical.

If the idea is purely to give us more info about ourselves, eh, can't say it seems necessary. If looking for top-ranked answers is something people do often on someone else's profile, then it might be handy.

Comment: If you were looking at a prospective new hire's profile to evaluate them. It could be beneficial.

Comment: @John - If you're using answer rank as a metric for the hiring of employees, I hope it's for a marketing or PR job and not a programming job.

Comment: @Peter - That might be a good point, I was just trying to think of a reason why it would be beneficial to others. I am sure there are other reasons, that was just the first to pop in my head.